# Is there a way to see a user's top tags relative to the global frequency of each tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm talking about the tags at the bottom of the info->stats page.

For example, let's say my #3 tag is C# and my #10 tag is LISP. However, C# occurs much more frequently on SO, so *relatively* I'm stronger in LISP than most users, but not necessarily stronger in C# than most users. Is there a way to see these counters in a relative way?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you hover over the tag, there is a ["Top Users"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lisp/topusers) link at the bottom of the pop-up. Is that what you want?</strike>

---

If you don't mind working with slightly old data, you could try running a query on SEDE to find out.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/105275/tag-rankings?UserId=326370) will list all the tags where you have a score of 1 or more and how many other users are doing better than you in it. Unfortunately it can get quite slow, if anyone has ideas on how to improve the performance, I'm happy to hear them.

Comment: It shows the top users, but as far as I can tell there's no way to tell my position in the list for a tag.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, because what I want to see is which tags *I'm* strong at, not which *users* are strong in each tag. What @Gabe said is one of the possible solutions - a page that would display my position in the list of top users for each tag.

Comment: would be nice to do it as a percentage rather than an absolute ranking otherwise its more or less a list of your tags in order of obscurity

Comment: also looks like a good way to find tags that shouldn't be tags

Comment: @jk: If you want to find tags that shouldn't be tags, you might get better results with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1266/per-tag-close-rate).